# Angular how to intercept going to external URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a use case where the app should not allow going to an external URL under certain conditions.

`$locationChangeStart` only allows me to intercept going to other locations within my application; but is there a way to detect when the user clicked on a link to goes to an external domain? I want to redirect to an some error page within my application when they click on a link to an external domain

Comment: by the way i'm on angular 1.5

Comment: You can create `a` directive that checks `href` attribute on click event. Probably it is better to make a separate directive for it, e.g. `external`.